# Cómo hago para que me diga la edad correcta mediante su año de nacimiento si la edad digitada es incorrecta

Tags: c++

Preguntar a un número de 5 estudiantes su edad y su fecha de nacimiento. Comprobar que la edad digitada corresponda al año de nacimiento. 
En caso contrario mostrar un mensaje diciendo que la edad no es verdadera y mostrarle la edad real de acuerdo al año de nacimiento.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int fn,fa,edad;

printf ("Introduce tu anio de nacimiento:");
scanf ("%d", & fn);

printf ("Introduce el anio actual:");
scanf ("%d", & fa);

edad = fa-fn;
printf("\n Tu edad es:%d", edad);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres es preguntar el año de nacimiento, luego el año actual y teniendo estos dos datos que muestre la edad del estudiante?

Comment: El problema es "Preguntar a un número de 5 estudiantes su edad y su fecha de nacimiento. Comprobar que la edad digitada corresponda al año de nacimiento. En caso contrario mostrar un mensaje diciendo que la edad no es verdadera y mostrarle la edad real de acuerdo al año de nacimiento.

Comment: Solo resta los dos años. Menos uno para esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera, lo he tipeado aqui mismo, pruebalo y me dices

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int nacimiento, actual, edad;

  for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
  cout<<"Ingresa el año de nacimiento" <<endl;
  cin>>nacimiento;

  cout<<"Ingresa el año actual" <<endl;
  cin>>actual;

   if(nacimiento >= actual){
    cout<<"El año de nacimiento no puede ser mayor o igual que el año actual" <<endl <<endl;
   }else{
     edad = actual - nacimiento;
     cout<<"La edad del estudiante es" <<" " <<edad <<" " <<"Anios" <<endl 
   <<endl;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Pregunta editada Oscar! Ya te deberia mostrar las 5 edades.

Comment: gracias amigo pero tengo un inconveniente, al poner el código me daba un error que decia que no habia sido declarada la variable y lo solucione pero al ejecutar el codigo me salio lo siguiente.Ingresa el a±o de nacimiento:1995
Ingresa el a±o actual:2018
Ingresa el a±o de nacimiento:1999
Ingresa el a±o actual:2018
Ingresa el a±o de nacimiento:1997
Ingresa el a±o actual:2018
Ingresa el a±o de nacimiento:1978
Ingresa el a±o actual:2018
Ingresa el a±o de nacimiento:2000
Ingresa el a±o actual:2018
18. de los 5 datos para cada edad solo me arrojo 1 :(

Comment: Metiste el cout<<edad dentro del ciclo for?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

int nacimiento, actual, edad;

for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
  cout<<"Ingresa el año de nacimiento:";
  cin>>nacimiento;

  cout<<"Ingresa el año actual:";
  cin>>actual;

   if(nacimiento >= actual){
     cout<<"El año de nacimiento no puede ser mayor o igual que el año actual";
    }else{
        edad = actual - nacimiento;
    }
  }
 cout<<edad;
 
}
este fue el codigo que ejecute no se si de pronto hice algo mal

Comment: El codigo esta bien, lo que pasa es que hacen falta unos saltos de linea para que puedas ver la edad de cada uno. Espera la edito, pero acabo de probar y si funciona bien.

Comment: @OscarManrique respuesta editada, he probado y funciona bien. Usa el codigo tal cual esta en la respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me salvaste.

Comment: De nada! Recuerda puntuar la respuesta! ;)